# How to setup twilio in my application

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio

From the last days i am struggling to how to use twilio in my ios app to make and receive a call with test credentials.Do i have to set up server for that and if yes then how to use the server and make call ? And if twilio does not allow to make call with test credentials ,how to make call with live paid credentials?

Please guide me .And pardon in case of any spelling mistake.

Any help is appreciated.

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio employee here. Check out the Quickstart docs on our website: it takes you step-by-step through the setup process for iOS: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client

Twilio will allow you to place phone calls and send SMS messages to numbers you have verified on your test account. Add your personal phone number to the Verified Called ID list here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified

I hope that helps!

Comment: Is it possible to not to use our server rather call the twilio api directly from iphone device.

Comment: Also i am getting this error from twilio i.e. "Thanku for using your demo account,please upgrade to premium account for calling".Is twilio paid for calling even from testing account

Comment: You can use the twilio REST API to send OUTbound sms and voice calls, but you cannot receive incoming without a server to respond the TwiML. You could use something like http://twimlbin.com if you only ever wanted a generic response, however.

Comment: Sending outbound and inbound voice calls should still work on the trial account - that voice snippet is played before your own TwiML is executed.

Comment: Hi phalt,I am able to make call now using my premium account,but the thing is that when i am making a call i m not getting any event which can tell me that call is actually connected and picked up at other end.Please suggest if i can do so.?

Comment: With the API you can query the call and see it's status: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties the ```status``` attribute provides the details you're after.